# Running C# ASP.net Soap Web Service in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, iis-7

I am currently working on a c# asp.net web project and I am trying to install the soap service to be used in iis7.

I have used Visual Studio to build a deployment package by selecting `Only files need to run the application` in the package/publish settings window.

I have then copied the contents of the built package to a location within my website but when I trying and access the service using `http://localhost/EmailSoapService/EmailSoapService.asmx` but I am getting an error. The error I'm getting is

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'EmailSoapService.EmailSoapService'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="EmailSoapService.asmx.cs" Class="EmailSoapService.EmailSoapService" %>

Source File: /EmailSoapService/EmailSoapService.asmx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

I don't understand why it is saying it can't find the .cs file. Admittedly this isn't on the server but as I selected to only export what's required to run the application, I assume the .cs file isn't required on the webserver.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A build package typically consists of a "bootstrap" executable that fires up an installer for the package. It sounds as though you copied the package, but didn't *install* the package, hence the site thinks it needs the core .cs files to accommodate the request. You can't just copy the build/deployment package - you typically need to deploy it to the destination server.

You might find some extra insight [here.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1081/building-a-web-deploy-package-from-visual-studio-2010/) Hope this is helpful. Good luck!